# Possible to use a "database first" approach in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Would it be possible to create a db schema in a GUI mysql administator and then create (or update) a model based on this schema?

Answer (score 4):

This is what migrations are for. Once you learn the DSL, writing migrations (esp. with the built-in generators) is much easier than fiddling with a GUI to create tables. Check out the [migrations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for detailed info.

ActiveRecord already does a lot automatically based on the database schema, such as adding getters and setters based on columns. I'm not sure what more you're wanting, so I dont know how to help you any more specifically.

Comment: I do not have a lot of experience with migrations but it seemed to me that once you had several migration files, managing them could become a nightmare (especially if you mistype a column name). You could end up getting boxed into a migration.

Comment: Using migrations also gives you a way of incrementally versioning changes to your schema which you can't do just by playing with your local db directly. If you've ever worked in a team or had to quickly deploy or roll back a change, this turns out to be pretty useful :)

Comment: Any app that isn't just out of the gate has at least a handful of migrations. It isn't uncommon for them to stack up so each deployment has several migrations, potentially from different developers and commits (probably even different feature branches). Migrations are a LOT safer than mucking with the database yourself, especially if you use SQLite or PostgreSQL (transactional schema changes). *I use MySQL on dev and it's a nightmare when a migration fails — don't do it if you can help it!*

Comment: @coreyward: what about the case where the database needs to be designed first and database developer handles all the deltas? I think that was what the OP meant. Or a case when the database was already created from a previous project.

Comment: Then `rake:schema:dump` and start modeling. You're on your own for how you manage changes to the production database and synchronize with app instances, though, so plan accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations might look confusing on first sight, but once you get used to them migrations work naturally in Rails. If you mistype a name, you just rollback and correct the migration file. Or write another migration that corrects the error in the rare case you used it on the production db.

They give you far more power, especially if your project went through several version stages. You can at any point rollback and migrate to any former state and when you add new columns you can easily set default values or write short ruby scripts that adjusts values or relations.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is asking if rails supports a database first approach, the answer I believe is no. If your familiar with .NET that supports both code and database approaches to app design.